# How do i rotate flash video every few minutes?

Tags: flash, video, rotation

I'd like to rotate flash video on my website after 5 minutes to a new video.  Autorotate it.

Answer (score 1):

by rotate, i think you mean play the next video in a series, right? you need to add an event listener to listen to the NetStatusEvent for the NetStream instance playing the flv. Once you get 'NetStream.Play.Stop' you know your video has stopped and you can fire up the next one.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use setInterval in combination with a tween to do the actual rotation.